# Array inside object with store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

I have this Redux store and reducer

```
const INITIAL_WORK = {
    departments: []
}
const works = (state = INITIal_WORK, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_DEPARTMENT':
            return {
                ...state,
                departments: [...state.department, action.item]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

In departments work people so I want to this people was inside a single department works people. So after fetch  data from db I want my store look like this:

```
const INITIAL_WORK = {
    departments: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "First department",
            people: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Johna Wayne"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Jessica Biel"
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "Bratt Pitt"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "second department",
            people: [
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: "Salma Hayek"
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    name: "Sylvester Stallone"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible create case in reducer which will be added people inside people array inside single department? How can I do that?

Comment: You can just use object/array destruction.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes, absolutely.

Let us assume your API returns payload as following.

{
 departmentId: `id of the department`
 id: `person id`
 name: `person name`
}

const INITIAL_WORK = {
    departments: []
}

const works = (state = INITIal_WORK, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_DEPARTMENT':
            return {
                ...state,
                departments: [...state.department, action.item]
            }

        case 'ADD_PERSON':
            const { departmentId, id, name } = action.item
            const departments = [...state.departments];

            departments[departmentId].people.push({id, name})
            return {
                 ...state,
                 departments
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Display only 1 element with 1 department. For example if I change `departments[departmentId]` to `departments[24]`, all items display with deparment 24..

Answer (score 0):

Combining [Immer.js](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) and `Redux` will be helpful for this case.

Here is a simple example of the difference that Immer could make in practice.

```js
// Reducer with inital state
const INITAL_STATE = {};
// Shortened, based on: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/src/reducers/products.js
const byId = (state = INITAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case RECEIVE_PRODUCTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.products.reduce((obj, product) => {
                    obj[product.id] = product
                    return obj
                }, {})
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

After using Immer, our reducer can be expressed as:

```js
import produce from "immer"

// Reducer with inital state
const INITAL_STATE = {};

const byId = produce((draft, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case RECEIVE_PRODUCTS:
            action.products.forEach(product => {
                draft[product.id] = product
            })
    }
}, INITAL_STATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let mergePeople=[];
INITIAL_WORK.departments.filter((cur,index)=>{
  cur.people.filter((person)=>{
   mergePeople.push(person);
  })
}
)
console.log(mergePeople);
```